# override custom scss variable inside another angular-cli(7) (library) project

Tags: angular, sass

I have two angular cli project (7)
one project that hold a library "core" generated with

```
$ng g library core
```

i use a file called "vars.sidebar.scss" to declare some variable like:

```
$sidebar-bg: #fff999 !default;
```

and then i use this file in the "sidebar.components.scss".

I have another project that want to consume the first project and modify the variable declared in the vars.sidebar.scss.

I dont understand how to do that...

EDIT 1:

---

here is my angular.json section about the core library:
https://pastebin.com/g2jb4wdy

the probleme, if i put the options:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": ["libs/core/src/lib"]
}
```

The cli : "ng build core" tell me:

```
    Schema validation failed with the following errors:
    Data path "" should NOT have additional 
    properties(stylePreprocessorOptions).
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume your library exposes a `_library.scss` with your stuff.
To import it from your app you need to configure that path into the `angular.json` of your app's `build.options`:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": ["libs/core/src/lib"]
}
```

Then you can `@import 'library';` from your App styles, and call a mixin that will include the styles of your library, just like Angular Material does with the `mat-light-theme` function:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/core/theming/_theming.scss

Before using those mixings (and maybe even before importing the library styles), you can customize the variables, and they will be used over the default ones.

I may confess that I import the Material theming, and after that I override some Material variables with my own one :)
Happy ng-coding!

Comment: Hi, I have a similar requirement but couldn't understand the answer mentioned above. Would you please elaborate the answer with sample code?

Comment: @suvenk you can import styles from your component with relative paths like `@import '../../../common/styles'` or using a central folder of styles configured in the `angular.json` build options you can `@import 'variables'`. What's your case?